# SSH keypair works in Putty but not in OpenSSH inside the Putty's session

Tags: ssh

I created a key pair with Puttygen, I putted its public key under /home/tiesto/.ssh/authorized_keys, I loaded its private key with Pageant, and logged in successfully with Putty via port 22. The private key has a passphrase.

`/home/tiesto/.ssh/` **is** `tiesto-tiesto-755`.

`/home/tiesto/.ssh/authorized_keys` **is** `tiesto-tiesto-600`.

### The problem:

When I try to use the very same key pair from **within** the Putty session (to start a tunnel on port 80 as well) I am being asked for the passphrase; I can fill the exact **correct** passphrase 3 times and in the third time I'm being told:

> Permission denied: Public key.

The command I use to login seems basically like this:

```
sudo ssh tiesto@111.111.111.111 -L 80:localhost:80 -i /home/tiesto/.ssh/tiesto_pri @ arbpid=$!
```

<sub>(The `arbpid=$!` is a variable I added to mark the specific process, please just ignore it).</sub>

### What's wired:

1. The same public key I use to start the Putty session is also under `/home/tiesto/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
2. The same private key I use to start the Putty session is under `/home/tiesto/.ssh/tiesto_pri`.

I double checked everything and don't know why it doesn't work.

You might have an idea what went wrong and why the very same key pair that works just fine for Putty, won't work inside the Putty session with OpenSSH for tunneling port80.

Comment: unfortunately, configuring and troubleshooting software is off-topic here - but I will say that the Puttygen keys are not compatible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224066/how-to-convert-ssh-keypairs-generated-using-puttygenwindows-into-key-pairs-use

Comment: Can I close this then? It's off-topic and your answer is in the link I provided.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for noting this as a possible cause; I do believe everything is fine besides that key incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putty uses its own privatekey format, called PPK, which is incompatible with OpenSSH. You can use puttygen to convert PPK to OpenSSH format (which is also OpenSSL 'legacy' format); see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74545/what-difference-between-openssh-key-and-putty-key .

`ssh` unfortunately assumes *any* error reading a keyfile must mean the password is wrong, so it repeatedly prompts for the password when it can't parse the file at all.

Comment: I gave you a thumb up. I thank you for your answer; Sadly even after I exported the ppk file to OpenSSH, and replaced it in Linux via sudo nano /.ssh tiesto_pri, and saved, I still have the exact same problem when trying to log in. I am still asked 3 times for the passphrase, and then get "permission denied (publick key).

Comment: @Benia: did `sudo` make the file owner root? I _think_ OpenSSH doesn't like that, but haven't tested. Next, use `openssl pkey <.ssh/tiesto_pri` to see if there's any detectable flaw in the file encryption and/or contents. If not, try `ssh` with `-vv` or maybe `-vvv` to see if anything in its log/debug info is helpful; if you need help with that I'm pretty sure you can edit your Q even with the hold.